# Searching for "1910" takes me to question 1910 instead

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, search

This is a weird one.

I tried searching for "1910" and instead of going to the search results, I was redirected to [question with id 1910](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/1910/was-death-traps-by-belton-y-cooper-historically-accurate) instead. I tried searching both from the header search box and the [search page](https://history.stackexchange.com/search), and even typed the search url ([history.stackexchange.com/search?q=1910](https://history.stackexchange.com/search?q=1910)) manually, but without success.

Searching for "1920" and every other year I tried [works normally](https://history.stackexchange.com/search?q=1920). I couldn't reproduce the bug on any other SE site.

Answer (score 4):

Searching for 1922 does the same thing (takes you to a question with the internal ID of 1922): https://history.stackexchange.com/search?q=1922

If I had to take a wild guess, based on my paltry knowledge of web CMS systems like Drupal, likely every item (question, tag wiki, etc) has a number in the backing database that runs SE. If your search query happens to be a number that matches a *question* page (rather than a tag wiki or something else), it assumes that's what you are looking for and brings up that question.

Hacking at it from the outside is about all the help I know how to provide though. This might be more of a meta.SE question, if you want Dev attention.

Comment: SE monitors per site Metas regularly, they might take a bit longer to see this here than they would if I had posted it on MSO, but they will see it. Now, this may very well be intentional and it might even make sense on Stack Overflow. But on History I suspect people searching by year wouldn't really expect to be redirected to a random question that has absolutely nothing to do with their search query.

Comment: @YannisRizos I certianly agree that here it is a "misfeature".

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is a bug... It's certainly unfortunate on this site where you might want to search by a specific year and some of those probably are also question IDs, but it looks like just a side-effect of question IDs taking precedence in the search.

Use quotes to force it to do a  text search instead of matching IDs: ["1910"](https://history.stackexchange.com/search?q=%221910%22). Or square brackets to force a tag search: [[1910]](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1910).

Comment: I can live with using quotes. That said, the behaviour is a bit counterintuitive (imho) and perhaps there should be an operator to force searching by question ID, instead of the ID taking precedence in the search. I'll see about posting a feature request to change the behaviour.